# Failure when under both tensile and shear stress

Tags: material-science, stress-strain, fracture

Suppose I have some element which is under both shear and tensile stress. I know the material properties for ultimate tensile stress and for ultimate shear stress.

However, presumably the material will break at a lower total stress then when both the ultimate shear and tensile stress would be applied. I'm not sure about this.

Is there some formula relating the ultimate shear stress and ultimate tensile stress to the ultimate combined stress?

How do I know when the material will break in such a combined loading scenario?

I'm looking for a simplified model, not the 100% accurate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a [3D failure criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_failure_theory). Pick the one most appropriate to your material type.

For ductile materials, for example, the [von Mises criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion) is frequently used. This criterion assumes—quite accurately—that hydrostatic stress of essentially any magnitude cannot disrupt any uniform solid and that only deviations from the hydrostatic state can lead to failure. (This is why the criterion appears graphically as a cylinder of safety around $\sigma_x=\sigma_y=\sigma_z$.)

Interestingly, it's not always the case that an additional load, even an additional load of the same sign (tensile or compressive), in another direction or mode necessarily brings the material closer to failure. Since ductile materials generally fail in shear, a material subjected to an x-direction normal stress $\sigma$ actually becomes less likely to fail if identical stresses are applied in the y- and z-directions, as the original resultant shear of $\sigma/2$ is reduced to zero under the latter equitriaxial stress state. Alternatively a shear stress of $\tau_{xy}$ can be alleviated by applying a pair of normal stresses $-\sigma_x$, ${\sigma_y}$. I wrote a little about this [here](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/Interpretation%20of%20Tresca%20(11-2-06).pdf) in the context of the [Tresca criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Tresca).

Edit: Hertzberg et al.'s *Deformation and Fracture Mechanics of Engineering Materials* and Kinloch's and Young's *Fracture Behaviour of Polymers* have extensive information on polypropylene fracture. I haven't used [this online resource](https://failurecriteria.com/index.html), Christensen's *Failure Theory for Materials Science and Engineering*, but it may be useful. For PLA information (especially for recent 3D printing applications), you may need to look at the recent literature, such as [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compositesb.2020.107894) and [here](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2017-0567).

Comment: That's very interesting. My materials are all thermoplastics. Does that narrow it down?

Comment: I've got to do the same analysis for PLA, which breaks, and also for PP, which yields.

Comment: Your first two links point to the same page. I can't find the 3D failure criterion.